# User defined Data type to JSON Object type casting using jason.simple

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, type-conversion

I have a user defined data type and I want that to be type casted in JSON Object. The data type is USERS.

I tried to type cast Users into String using `.toString()` but the output came something different and incorrect. Then I thought of type casting that into JSON Object and then return the result. I want the function to return a data type that can be easily type casted to another.

At first I used this (This - `userDao.findOne(k)` returns a Users type data):

```
String u= userDao.findOne(k).toString();
```

The result came as :

```
com.techprimers.db.model.Users@680b74e5
```

I don't know what is getting wrong there.
But when I am using return type as Users, the result is:

```
{
  "id"="Gohan_123",
  "value"=789,
  "Anime"="Dragon Ball Z"
}
```

I want to convert those Users to JSON Object using JSON.simple but any other packages will also not be a problem.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is your question? return type of User gives you whay you need right?

Comment: This is returning you the address [Stored Locally] of userDao.findOne(k) in string

Comment: @ANANDSONI So, how can I bring the output through that? I understand what you said but there will be some way to do that right?

Comment: @Deadpool But I want that in return type String or JSON Object. Not in User . I want to type cast User to either of them. I tried String but that didn't give the required output.

Comment: What you expecting in result...A JSON format?

Comment: Okay, so In your User class, add toString() function. Like this

Comment: @ANANDSONI I just want to type cast it either to String or to a JSON Object.

Comment: @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" +
                "id=" + id +","+
                "value=" + value +","+
                "Anime =+ anime + "}";
             
    }

Comment: Key is if you will override toString() method in your model class. It will work. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195002/discussion-between-anand-soni-and-chaos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that use a small trick, *Override toString()* method in your Object class (here **User**) like

```
public class User {

    String id;
    int value;
    String Anime;

    .
    .
    .
    //Getter Setter 
    .
    .
    .

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" +
            "id=" + id + "," +
            "value=" + value + ","+
            "Anime='" + Anime +
            "}";
    }

}
```